# Creating a JS function that colors a specific cell

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a separate function that once a table has been generated, a value x and y can be placed within the input and it will highlight the desired cell a certain colour.

My issue arises when I try to select the cell specifically, my code breaks down at

```
var change  = document.getElementById("table").tr[rowIndex].td[cellIndex];
```

```js
// functions to create values of r and c
function GenerateTable() {

    var tblBody = document.createElement("tbody");
    for (var i = 0; i < irow.value; i++) {

        var row = document.createElement("tr");

        for (var j = 0; j < icol.value; j++) {
            var cell = document.createElement("td");
            row.appendChild(cell)
        }


        tblBody.appendChild(row);
    }
    var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
    var tbl = document.createElement("table");
    tbl.appendChild(tblBody);
    body.appendChild(tbl);

}

//selector function
function SelectCell() {

    //grab value from the input x and y
    var tr = document.getElementsByTagName("tr");
    var td = document.getElementsByTagName("td");


    //insert the value of x and y into an array retriever

    var rowIndex = document.getElementById("valy").value;
    var cellIndex = document.getElementById("valx").value;
    //*********BREAKS DOWN HERE*******
    var change = document.getElementById("table").tr[rowIndex].td[cellIndex];

    change.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    //change color of specific coord            
}
```

```html
<label>Rows</label>
<input type="number" id="irow">
<label>Cols</label>
<input type="number" id="icol">
<input type="submit" id="smit1">
<input type="number" id="valx" placeholder="x">
<input type="number" id="valy" placeholder="y">
<input type="submit" id="smit2">

<table id="table">

</table>
```

Comment: have you tried printing what's in your variables? Try `console.log(td);`

Comment: I have used debugger and it shows that the values are correct and stored in valy and valx correctly, but it then goes on to say that it cannot read property of "2" of undefined or whatever my value is..

Comment: You should look, what's in `td`. My first comment shows how to do that. Then you'll see what's wrong with your approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure you can chain it like this:

`var change  = document.getElementById("table").tr[rowIndex].td[cellIndex];`

I think what you want is:

```
//grab value from the input x and y
var rowIndex = +document.getElementById('valy').value;
var cellIndex = +document.getElementById('valx').value;

// Get reference to the table
var table = document.getElementById('table');
// Get the tr of the table with the index rowIndex
var tr = table.querySelectorAll('tr')[rowIndex];

// Query the selected row for all column elements and select the one at the needed index
var change = tr.querySelectorAll('td')[cellIndex];
```

NOTE: It's probably best to validate the values in the input before trying to retrieve the DOM element to ensure the code does not break if the user enters a non integer value or a value which is out of bounds

Comment: I see, what was it about my initial version that wouldn't work? edit - Works perfectly now, many thanks!

Comment: @ClutchBleu You tried to access the table rows as `document.getElementById("table").tr` - you can't do that.  `tr` is not a property of a table element.  The above code searches the table element and finds the tr elements, then searches the relevant tr and finds the td.

Comment: `document.getElementById("table")` returns the DOM reference to the table. It will not have properties like `tr` and `td` which is what `document.getElementById("table").tr[rowIndex]` is trying to do.. So your error is saying 'I don't know what `tr` is so I cant read the property `2` of undefined'

Answer (score 3):

*Since I finished it anyway:*

**Here is a working example**

```js
var irow = document.querySelector('#irow');
var icol = document.querySelector('#icol');
var smit1 = document.querySelector('#smit1');
var valx = document.querySelector('#valx');
var valy = document.querySelector('#valy');
var smit2 = document.querySelector('#smit2');

function GenerateTable() {
  var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
  var tbl = document.createElement("table");
  var tblBody = document.createElement("tbody");

  for (var i = 0; i < irow.value; i++) {
    var row = document.createElement("tr");

    for (var j = 0; j < icol.value; j++) {
      var cell = document.createElement("td");

      row.appendChild(cell)
    }

    tblBody.appendChild(row);
  }

  tbl.setAttribute('class', 'generated');
  tbl.appendChild(tblBody);
  body.appendChild(tbl);
  smit1.disabled = true;
  irow.disabled = true;
  icol.disabled = true;
  smit2.disabled = false;
  valx.disabled = false;
  valy.disabled = false;
}

function SelectCell() {
  var tr = document.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  var td = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
  var rowIndex = valy.value;
  var cellIndex = valx.value;
  var change = document.querySelector('table.generated tbody').children[rowIndex].children[cellIndex];

  change.style.backgroundColor = "red";  
}

smit1.addEventListener('click', GenerateTable);
smit2.addEventListener('click', SelectCell);
```

```css
table.generated td {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}

.width100 {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="width100">
    <input type="number" id="irow" placeholder="rows">
    <input type="number" id="icol" placeholder="cols">
    <input type="submit" id="smit1">
  </div>
  <div class="width100">
    <input type="number" id="valx" disabled="true" placeholder="x">
    <input type="number" id="valy" disabled="true" placeholder="y">
    <input type="submit" id="smit2" disabled="true">
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Nice working snippet.. Would it make sense to clear a previously coloured cell when another cell is coloured? OP does not mention this so I guess this works too. Input validation would be an helpful addition as well

Comment: @ChiragRavindra I thought about that too, but since the specifications for the question do not require that specific behaviour I did not include it

Comment: Makes sense.. :)